# Python arguments inside triple quotes

Tags: python, mysql, string, string-interpolation

I have a python script that contains a sql query. I use triple quotes around the sql query for formatting purposes. I'd like to inject variables that I populate from the command line into the query. How can I do this while preserving the triple quotes. Are there better ways to get around the triple quotes?

Ex:

```
AGE = raw_input("Enter your age: ")

vdf = vertica.select_dataframe("""
    Select
        col1
        col2
        coln
    FROM
        TableX
    WHERE
        col2 IN (21, 22, AGE)
    Group BY 1
""")
```

Comment: make sure to sanitise your input

Comment: I would be careful about passing anything a user enters using str.format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am surprised, that the fabulous `%` operator is not mentioned, pythons build in string formatting would make your original lines work with a tiny modification:

```
AGE = raw_input("Enter your age: ")

vdf = vertica.select_dataframe("""
    Select
        col1,
        col2,
        coln
    FROM
        TableX
    WHERE
        col2 IN (21, 22, %s)
    Group BY 1
""" % AGE)
```

This would also work for queries with multiple arguments:

```
AGE = raw_input("Enter your age: ")
GENDER = raw_input("Enter your gender (m/f): ")
HEIGHT = raw_input("Enter your height in cm: ")

vdf = vertica.select_dataframe("""
    INSERT INTO stats (
        age,
        gender,
        height
    )
    VALUES
    (
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s'
    )
""" % ( AGE, GENDER, HEIGHT ))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) like this:

```
AGE = raw_input("Enter your age: ")
query_1 = """
    Select
        col1
        col2
        coln
    FROM
        TableX
    WHERE
        col2 IN (21, 22, {})
    Group BY 1
"""
vdf = vertica.select_dataframe(query_1.format(AGE))
```

A simple example with triple quotes and multiple assignments is:

```
>>> age = 100
>>> name = "koukouviou"
>>> """I am {} and I am {} years old""".format(name, age)
'I am koukouviou and I am 100 years old'
```

Comment: I edited the question have a look. Basically you add more `{}` to your string and include them in your `format()` assignments

Answer (score 2):

You could make the query string separate and use format to put correct age, e.g.:

```
a_query = """
    Select
        col1
        col2
        coln
    FROM
        TableX
    WHERE
        col2 IN (21, 22, {})
    Group BY 1
"""

vdf = vertica.select_dataframe(a_query.format(AGE))
```

Comment: My connection's shaky didn't see you posted basically the same thing.. +1 :)

Comment: @koukouviou Yep, our answers are same, which  indicates that it is most likely the right way of doing what OP is trying to do.

Comment: How would you include multiple inputs? (e.g. a second raw input injected into a second WHERE clause)

Comment: @csjnkns same. Have a look how format works. It can take multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I will add one more answer with a `dict` unpacking as it made my life much simpler. Using @hexerei-software's `INSERT` example:

```
AGE = raw_input("Enter your age: ")
GENDER = raw_input("Enter your gender (m/f): ")
HEIGHT = raw_input("Enter your height in cm: ")

settings = {'AGE': AGE, 'GENDER': GENDER, 'HEIGHT': HEIGHT}

vdf = vertica.select_dataframe("""
    INSERT INTO stats (
        age,
        gender,
        height
    )
    VALUES
    (
        '{AGE}',
        '{GENDER}',
        '{HEIGHT}'
    )
""".format(**settings))
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)!

```
vdf = vertica.select_dataframe(f"""
    Select
        col1
        col2
        coln
    FROM
        TableX
    WHERE
        col2 IN (21, 22, {AGE})
    Group BY 1
""")
```